# How to get a PhoneGap based app to authenticate against an ASP.NET Forms Authentication backend?

Tags: asp.net, cordova, forms-authentication

Has anyone managed to get ASP.NET Forms Authentication (with cookies) working with a PhoneGap based mobile application?

I have come across the following questions about managing cookies within PhoneGap and configuring the server properly:

- [Where cookie is managed in phonegap app with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124300/where-cookie-is-managed-in-phonegap-app-with-jquery)
- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/190
- [Asp.Net Forms Authentication when using iPhone UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158550/problem-with-asp-net-forms-authentication-when-using-iphone-uiwebview)

But unfortunately neither of these solutions work. The requests coming from a PhoneGap application do not indicate an authenticated user even though when I run the same dashboard.html code as a file in Safari the requests show up as authenticated.

Comment: Have you had any luck resolving this?

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## SOLUTION:

`cookieless="UseCookies"` in web.config **FINALLY** did it for me:

```xml
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" /> 
    </authentication>
```

REF: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/Thj0fS2GDh4

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a cookie in a phonegap app, you're basically creating a cookie for the localhost. When you go out to the .net server, that server can't see that cookie.

This is very general, but I hope that this helps a little?

Answer (score 0):

You may use in web.config , cookieless="UseCookies" in authentication tag

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your requirements, this may be a silly answer, but, why you don't consider in this case to deliver the functionality not from a ASP.NET service but from a WCF/Service Stack service?

I'm currently working also in a PhoneGap application but it is served by a REST web service (Service Stack) and I think this kind of architecture offers a lot of flexibility.