# Not able to set domain in document.cookie in Phonegap iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, session-cookies

In phonegap iOS build When i set a cookie using document.cookie with domain for storing session values i"m not able to do it.

It's giving me empty cookie when i retrieved. Could you please guide me how to set cookies with domain in Phonegap iOS applications.

When i try setting cookies without domain its working fine. But my request will fail without domain.
I used below code.

```
document.cookie = "SESSION=" + SESSION +"; path=/; domain=.facebook.com";

but when i try below code its working.

document.cookie = "SMSESSION=" + SMSESSION +"; path=/;";
```

but without session my app will fail.

also tried document.domain, its breaking my javascript code.

Comment: I don't know about `cookie` but storing values can be done also using `local Storage`. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved my problem. To set the cookies i have created phonegap plugin and used native http client. After setting up cookies and domain via native client, the normal http client using javascript is working fine.

The iOS phonegap plugin code to set the cookies.

```
NSDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @".domain.com", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                              @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                              @"SESSION", NSHTTPCookieName,
                              @"Session value",NSHTTPCookieValue,nil];
NSDictionary *cookieProperties1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @".domain.com", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                              @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                              @"some cookie", NSHTTPCookieName,
                              @"some cookie value",NSHTTPCookieValue,nil];

NSHTTPCookie *cookie1 = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties1];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
NSArray* cookieArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookie,cookie1, nil];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:cookieArray forURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:urlString] mainDocumentURL:nil];
```

After setting up cookies in cookie storage Create NSURLConnection and perform the sync or async request.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below url

[Where cookie is managed in phonegap app with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124300/where-cookie-is-managed-in-phonegap-app-with-jquery)

you have to set below code in appdelegate.m

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage 
                                  sharedHTTPCookieStorage]; 
[cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

and in phonegap

```
var request =   {
            url: my_server_url,
            success: function(response, status, request) {
                var header = request.getAllResponseHeaders();
                var match = header.match(/(Set-Cookie|set-cookie): (.+?);/);
                if(match)
                    my_saved_cookie = match[2];
            },
            }

if(my_saved_cookie)
request.headers = { Cookie: my_saved_cookie };

$.ajax(request);
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Its not about retrieving it. Problem is my application is not able to set the cookie with domain.

Comment: Can you tell me exact requirement. why you want to set cookies for facebook?

Comment: Its not for facebook alone. instead of my actual domain i used facebook. it can be any domain. I want to set the session values and doamin in cookies using javascript in phonegap iOS application.

Comment: I personally suggest dont go for that way. just do one thing login through facebook/twitter etc. fetch their id, store that id and domail in localStorage and maintain your functionality that way. because It has creating problem with cookies in phonegap app.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. If you store cookies and when we make request the cookie values are automatically taken. This functionality is already implemented in desktop version of same app and its working fine. Now I'm migrating desktop version into iPad using Phonegap.

Comment: desktop version and phonegap version both are totally different. you can not make it exactly same. Yes that was true that cookie will take their value automatically but for phonegap you have to maintain it differently.